# How to check if a set of values exist in item table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, set, product, exists

I have two table- 'Order' and 'Order Item'.

- Order table contains-
  Order Number, Order Date, etc.
- Order Item table contains-
  Order Number, Order Item Number, Product Name, etc.

The joining condition between these two tables is on Order Number.

In my target table I need orders and a flag. The flag should tell, if there is a predefined set of products which has been ordered as part of that order then it should be set to 'Yes'.

E.g., Suppose an order 'ORD-01' contains three products in Order Item table - 'Mobile', 'PC' and 'Tablet', then my resulting table should contain Order Number as ORD-01 and Flag as 'Yes'.
In the same way, if order 'ORD-02' contains only two prods 'Mobile' an 'Tablet', then the resulting table should contains 'ORD-02' and Flag 'No'.
Similarly, if order 'ORD-03' contains three different prods '**Notebook**', 'PC' an 'Tablet', then the resulting table should contains 'ORD-03' and Flag 'No'.

As per my understanding, I have written below query-

```
SELECT order_number,(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT product_name)>=3     
THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END Prod_Flag 
FROM order_item b
WHERE a.order_number=b.order_number
AND b.product_name IN ('Mobile','PC','Tablet'))
FROM order a
WHERE order_date>last_run_date;
```

But it takes too much of time, as the order item is a very big table (>1 Billion rows). However I need incremental data based upon order date from Order table. Even if there is an index of order number in both tables, it takes time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might improve the reading experience by having a peak at the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your query is right. As I understood, you wish to raise it's speed. If so, there are several ways you can try.

You can consider to put these tables into indexed cluster. It will store the data physically joined so querying would require less physical reads.

For this query, server should scan two tables: one for appropriate dates (eigther full table scan or index scan), other for products and joins the results by reading ORDER_NUMBER via rowid. It isn't very fast anyway. The simpliest way is to add (ORDER_DATE, ORDER_NUMBER) index for ORDERs and (ORDER_NUMBER, PRODUCT_NAME) index for ORDER_ITEMs; it will allow to use indexes only.

Maybe it would be suitable to make a fast-refreshable materialized view, something like

```
create materialized view as
select 
  a.order_date, 
  a.order_number,
  sum(case when b.product_name = 'Mobile' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_mobiles,
  sum(case when b.product_name = 'PC' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_pcs,
  sum(case when b.product_name = 'Tablet' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_tablets
from
  order a, order_item b
where
  a.order_number = b.order_number
group by
  a.order_number, a.order_date
```

If it would be impossible to make this fast-refreshable, you can do equal thing manually using trigger. Anyway, in this case you'll get precalculated data ready to check.

Comment: Thanks Sanders for your answer, but what I was thinking, if we could get an alternate way of deriving this flag by using some 'exists' clause (as exists is considered faster). But I am not getting the way to write it in this scenario.

Comment: You're definitely wrong. MV with aggregates can be fast-refreshable. For example, if it contains SUM(field), fast refresh would add :new.field - :old.field when processing MV log. If it contains count(*), it would add and/or subtract one. And so on. See http://www.adellera.it/blog/2013/08/19/fast-refresh-of-aggregate-only-materialized-views-with-sum-algorithm/ for example.

Comment: @SanderstheSoftwarer, Ok, my comment was to generic, however there are some restrictions: [Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Aggregates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm#i1007028). I don't know whether `count(case when b.product_name = 'Mobile' then 1 else 0 end)` works out.

Comment: Yes, I didn't check it too. That's why I said 'if would be impossible'.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Would a query like this get you to your result any quicker?

```
SELECT ON.ORDER_NUMBER,
   CASE WHEN SET_FOUND.ORDER_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
   THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END PROD_FLAG
FROM ORDER ON,
(SELECT ORDER_NUMBER
   FROM ORDER_ITEM
  WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'Mobile'
 INTERSECT
 SELECT ORDER_NUMBER
   FROM ORDER_ITEM
  WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'PC'
 INTERSECT
 SELECT ORDER_NUMBER
   FROM ORDER_ITEM
  WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'Tablet') SET_FOUND
WHERE ON.ORDER_NUMBER = SET_FOUND.ORDER_NUMBER (+)
```

Comment: This query is also taking time, as it is doing full table scan in order item table.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be this one:

```
WITH t AS
   (SELECT product_name, order_number
   FROM order_item
   WHERE product_name IN ('Mobile','PC','Tablet')
   GROUP BY order_number, product_name)
SELECT order_number, 
   CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT product_name) >= 3 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM t
   JOIN order USING (order_number)
GROUP BY order_number
```

Comment: It is also taking time.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order number an increasing sequence number? If so the one approach would be to limit data selected from the order_item, which you said is a large table, by putting condition on order_number, which you said is an indexed column. I assume last_run_date signifficantly limits number of concerned orders.
If so you can:

```
select min(order_number) into order_num_from from Order where       order_date>last_run_date
```

and then make your query

```
SELECT order_number,(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT product_name)>=3     
THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END Prod_Flag 
FROM order_item b
WHERE a.order_number=b.order_number
AND b.order_number> order_num_from
AND b.product_name IN ('Mobile','PC','Tablet'))
FROM order a
WHERE order_date>last_run_date;
```

If this runs significantly faster (I didn't see explain plan, so this is just an idea how to avoid full table scan ), put an index on order_date column and eventually make finding order_num_from into subquery to have one single query.

Comment: Sorry, but it is alphanumeric and non sequential.